# How to add totals of array list object data after populating the array using a separate method

Tags: java, arrays

initialized the second array dimension but still getting a null pointer exception.

```
    final int LIQUORINV = 8;
    final int EACHCOUNT = 10;
    Liquor[][] invLiquor = new Liquor[LIQUORINV][EACHCOUNT];
    for( int i=0; i <= invLiquor.length; i++){
        System.out.println("\nWhich liquor are we counting?");
        String type = keyboard.next();
        for( int j=0; j < invLiquor[i].length; j++){
            invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorType(type);
            invLiquor[i][j] = new Liquor();
            System.out.println("What is the product name?: ");
            invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorName(keyboard.next());
            System.out.println("What is the count?: ");
            invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorCount(keyboard.nextDouble());
            System.out.println("What is the cost?: ");
            invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorCost(keyboard.nextDouble());
        }
    }
```

I think I did fix this next part however. so that's solved at least.

```
public static double GetLiquorCostTotal(Liquor[][] inv){
    double totalCost = 0;
    for( int i=0; i < inv.length; i++){
        double sum = 0;
        for( int j=0; j < inv[i].length; j++){
            sum += (inv[i][j].getLiquorCost() * inv[i][j].getLiquorCount());
        }
        System.out.println("\nThe total cost of the " + inv[i][0].getLiquorType() + 
            " inventory is: $" + sum);
        totalCost+=sum;
    }
    return totalCost;
}
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `Liquor[] invLiquor = new Liquor[sizeLiquor];` and `Liquor[] inv = new Liquor[sizeInv];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is your `invLiquor` array. My guess is you want to use `invLiquor` to store all the `inv`s. In it's current form `invLiquor` does not have any association with `inv`s. You might want to use a `2D array` of `Liquor`, where the `row` will be the `liquor` categories. Here is a `pseudo` code that might be helpful.

```
// m = category count; n = item in each category;

Liquor[][] invLiquor = new Liquor[m][n]; 
 
for(int i=0;i<invLiquor.length();i++){
    System.out.println("\nWhich liquor are we counting?");
    String type = keyboard.next();
    
    for(int j=0;j<invLiquor[i].length();j++){
         invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorType(type);
         invLiquor[i][j] = new Liquor();
         System.out.println("What is the product name?: ");
         invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorName(keyboard.next());
         System.out.println("What is the count?: ");
         invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorCount(keyboard.nextDouble());
         System.out.println("What is the cost?: ");
         invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorCost(keyboard.nextDouble());
    }

}
double thisLiquorTotal = GetCostTotal(invLiquor);
System.out.println("\nThe total cost of the liquor inventory is: $" + thisLiquorTotal);

// the GetCostTotal method
double GetCostTotal(Liquor[][] invLiquor){
    double totalCost = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<invLiquor.length();i++){
       double sum = 0;
       for(int j=0;j<invLiquor[i].length();j++){
          sum+=invLiquor[i][j];
       }
       System.out.println("\nThe total cost of the " + invLiquor[i][0].getLiquorType() + 
            " inventory is: $" + sum);
       totalCost+=sum;

    }
   return totalCost;
}
```

This is a simple demo with a fixed number of `Liquor` in each category. If you want to have a different number of `Liquor` in different categories you might use an `Array` of `Collections` like `LinkedList`or `ArrayList`.

Comment: I figured I should be using a 2d array but wasn't completely sure how to go about  doing that. This looks like it should solve my problems, thank you so much. I'll respond to this again tomorrow morning to confirm I've gotten it down. I really appreciate it- thanks you so much.

Comment: You should accept the answer if this worked for you.

Comment: another edit. got the costTotal method to work. just having trouble figuring out how to populate the 2d array correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the setLiquorType(type) part in the wrong spot. Answer below. Thanks all!

```
    System.out.println("\nLet's start with liquor.");
            System.out.println("How many different liquors are we counting today?: ");
            final int LIQUORINV = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("How man of each liquor?: ");
            final int EACHCOUNT = keyboard.nextInt();
            Liquor[][] invLiquor = new Liquor[LIQUORINV][EACHCOUNT];
            for( int i=0; i < invLiquor.length; i++){    
                System.out.println("\nWhich liquor are we counting?");
                String type = keyboard.next();
                for( int j=0; j < invLiquor[i].length; j++){
                    invLiquor[i][j] = new Liquor();
                    invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorType(type);
                    System.out.println("What is the product name?: ");
                    invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorName(keyboard.next());
                    System.out.println("What is the count?: ");
                    invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorCount(keyboard.nextDouble());
                    System.out.println("What is the cost?: ");
                    invLiquor[i][j].setLiquorCost(keyboard.nextDouble());
                }

double liquorCost = GetLiquorCostTotal(invLiquor);
        System.out.println("\nThe total cost of the liquor inventory is: $" + liquorCost);

public static double GetLiquorCostTotal(Liquor[][] inv){
        double totalCost = 0;
        for( int i=0; i < inv.length; i++){
            double sum = 0;
            for( int j=0; j < inv[i].length; j++){
                sum += (inv[i][j].getLiquorCost() * inv[i][j].getLiquorCount());
            }
            totalCost+=sum;
        }
        return totalCost;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).